Detecting schema inconsistencies in json data with Dask bag
I have spent a few days trying to battle an issue with json data and dask, so I finally resort to asking here.
I have a collection of json files who should all have the same data structure containing arrays of integers. I load them all with Dask bag and try to enforce the corresponding schema but keep running into a type error whenever I run to_parquet(). I have passed the meta argument to the to_dataframe() function to indicate the type I should have in the dataframe but I keep getting the following error:

    name: string
    time_ticks: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    Anger: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    Sadness: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    BeatImpact: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    Tenderness: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    TempoFeel: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    Sensuality: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    Joy: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    Fear: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64

Received partition schema:
    __null_dask_index__: int64
    name: string
    time_ticks: string
    Anger: string
    Sadness: string
    BeatImpact: string
    Tenderness: string
    TempoFeel: string
    Sensuality: string
    Joy: string
    Fear: string

I have tried many things, including filtering out the bag to make sure I am only left with the right data, but I can't get passed this error. When I check my json files manually they seem ok, but it seems that some of the data is leading Dask to think that they are all strings for some reason!

Could you give the full error and also the code you are using?
